# Nvenc produces corrupted video

Tags: linux, nvenc

Someone knows how to solve this?

1. 
2. 

## Hardware:

- DRIVER: 396.24
- CPU: Ryzen 1700
- GPU: Nvidia MSI 1050 TI

## Settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a known bug in ssrr: https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/issues/658

**SOLUTION:** You can use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), which is compatible with NVENC.